# WSO2 IS 5.9.0 Updating user claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have two problems, when use the method `setUserClaimValue` from `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` SOAP endpoint, the update, works good.

But, the endpont `/userinfo` lost the values, I need to re-authenticate the user for generate a new access token and all works good again.

I need use the method `setUserClaimValue` from `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` for update more than one claim, but nothing happend, I don't have any error but the claims were not updated.

This is my env:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:setUserClaimValues>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>username@mail.com</ser:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ser:claims>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:claimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</xsd:claimURI>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:value>newemail@mail.com</xsd:value>
         </ser:claims>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:profileName></ser:profileName>
      </ser:setUserClaimValues>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What method I should use for update more thant one claim?
Why when update claims, my actual access token lost data from /userinfo endpoint, and is it necessary to generate a new access token?

Comment: Did you try providing profileName value as "default"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

> What method I should use for update more thant one claim?

You have to use `setUserClaimValues` from `RemoteUserStoreManagerService`. You can follow this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-setUserClaimValues()) for further information on this `RemoteUserStoreManagerService`.

A sample soap service is given below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:setUserClaimValues>
         <ser:userName>piraveena</ser:userName>
         <ser:claims>
            <xsd:claimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/organization</xsd:claimURI>
            <xsd:value>wso2</xsd:value>
         </ser:claims>
         <ser:claims>
            <xsd:claimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/country</xsd:claimURI>
            <xsd:value>srilanka</xsd:value>
         </ser:claims>
         <ser:profileName>default</ser:profileName>
      </ser:setUserClaimValues>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

2)

> Why when update claims, my actual access token lost data from
>   /userinfo endpoint?

I couldn't reproduce this issue locally. I was able to obtain the userclaims without reauthenticating even after updating the claims via admin service.

When user claim is updated, the userattribute cache which is mapped against the accesstoken also will be cleared by an event. So the next time when you call the useinfo endpoint, the cache will be empty. In that case, the claim will be obtained from userstore. Please refer to this [code](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/v6.2.28/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/endpoint/util/ClaimUtil.java#L87) here. Due to this, the user doesn't need to reauthenticate since the userattributes exist in the userstore.

But you may face this issue when you have enabled email as username and you update the email of the user via the service.